# How get data of Array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this Array:

[image]

So, the problem I have I try to get the data under "DETALLES" and "AREAS".

But I don't know how.
If I try to use {{$da->name}} this give me the name of the Hospital.
But what I need to access the other data...

My controller:

```
   public function findHospitalSearch(Request $request){
    $data =  Hospitales::where('estado', $request->estado)->get();
    foreach($data as $d){
        $return = $d::with('detalles')->with('areas')->get();
    }  
    return view('sistema.findHospitalResult',compact('return'));
}
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as a picture

Comment: The pic, is just the Array - But thanks
I try to put as a code, but it distorts

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are doing it completely wrong. When you are using:

```
foreach($data as $d){
    $return = $d::with('detalles')->with('areas')->get();
}
```

you are overriding result in loop over and over.

Controller code should rather look like this:

```
public function findHospitalSearch(Request $request)
{
    $hospitals = Hospitales::where('estado', $request->estado)
                   ->with('detalles', 'areas')->get();

    return view('sistema.findHospitalResult', compact('hospitals'));
}
```

Now in your view you can use something like this:

```
@foreach ($hospitals as $hospital)
   {{ $hospital->nombre }}<br />
   {{ $hospital->detalles->sitioWeb }}<br />
   @foreach ($hospital->areas as $area}
     {{ $area->area }}<br />
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```